# global fixture that injects values from current module

Tags: pytest

I have test modules of this style:

```
#test_mammals.py:

PETS = ['cats', 'dogs']

def test_mammals_1(pet):
    assert 0, pet

def test_mammals_2(pet):
    assert 0, pet
```

And here another one:

```
#test_birds.py:

PETS = ['budgie', 'parrot']

def test_birds_1(pet):
    assert 0, pet

def test_birds_2(pet):
    assert 0, pet
```

And I would like to define the fixture "pet" only once:

```
#conftest.py:

import pytest

@pytest.fixture(scope='module', autouse=True)
def getpets(request):
    return getattr(request.module, 'PETS', [])

@pytest.fixture(scope='module', params=getpets, autouse=True)
def pet(request):
    return request.param
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work because "pet" expects a list for "params". But if I put "getpets" into a list the ficture will return a pointer to "getpets" but not the values from "PETS" from the corresponding module.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit hard to answer because your code doesn't make a lot of sense as it stands - if your 'PETS' really are just a list of strings, you should just use [pytest.mark.parametrize](http://pytest.org/latest/parametrize.html#pytest-mark-parametrize-parametrizing-test-functions) and you don't need anything special in conftest, or any fixture, in fact.

However if you have something more complicated happening, probably the easiest thing to do is have a generic fixture in conftest, and in each test module, define a lightweight fixture that has your specific data for that module, that makes use of your generic `pet` fixture in whatever way it needs to.